# Can't create Couchbase bucket - invalid authType

Tags: couchbase

I'm using Couchbase server HTTP API to create a bucket. 
When I issue a POST request to:

```
http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets?name=Test&proxyPort=12259&ramQuotaMB=200&authType=sasl&replicaNumber=1&saslPassword=123456
```

it returns:

```
"errors": {
    "authType": "invalid authType"
}
```

I've set Authorization and Content-Type headers but still no luck. I use 2.5.1. What did I miss here? Couchbase docs does not say anything about incorrect authType

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to create a sasl-authenticated bucketed on a port other than 11211?

> SASL authenticating Couchbase buckets may only be placed on port 11211
>   and each bucket is differentiated by its name and password. SASL
>   bucket may not be placed on any other port beside 11211. These buckets
>   can be reached with either a vBucket aware smart client or a binary
>   client that has SASL support. These buckets cannot be reached with
>   ASCII clients.

refer to: http://docs.pub.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/

Comment: right. I should've known I didn't read the docs long enough. thanks a lot

Comment: I changed port number - it still doesn't solve the problem, same error message

Comment: what if you dont specify it at all?